# HttpMultipartFormDataContent.Dispose throws ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, uwp

The following code on a UWP project throws ObjectDisposedException (targeting Windows 10 Anniversary Edition - 14393):

```
using (var content = new HttpMultipartFormDataContent())
{
    //Why disposing of the content raises an exception?
}
```

The exception message is: `Additional information: The object has been closed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80000013)`

Stack trace: `at System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.IClosable.Close()
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.IClosableToIDisposableAdapter.Dispose()
   at App3.MainPage.ButtonBase_OnClick(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`

Does it mean that although `HttpMultipartFormDataContent` implements `IDisposable` it should not be disposed of?

Will my app be ok if I don't dispose of `HttpMultiparFormDataContent` type objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting the bug/problem. Not calling Dispose in the above case/scenario, won't necessarily cause memory leak problems for you and memory should be reclaimed back. You may notice an increase in memory, but not necessarily a memory leak. You can check it yourself by starting a diagnostic session in Visual Studio (Debug -> Performance Profiler -> Memory)